# Rails No Method Error for Schedule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I seem to be having a separate problem from the other guy who posted something like this.  The following comes when I just go to my homepage which should have a form...

[image]

Any ideas on this sort of problem?

I am using Rails 3.0.1 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: Is `ticket` an actual attribute, or a virtual one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's suggesting your schedule model doesn't have a `ticket` method/column - does it exist? Have you run your migrates etc?

Comment: I don't think this is the issue... a missing column would result in a `undefined method 'ticket' for #<Schedule>` error.

Comment: Thanks, my overall problem wasn't necessarily to do just a simple migrate with the rails command.  I needed to do $ rake db:schema:load

Comment: It actually was a missing column @zeantsoi, but once the schema loaded up the database was filled with the correct columns